# Why are Pokemon so difficult to find for me?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a suburban town outside of Harrisburg, Pa. I know people who get swarmed by Pokemon where I live in Pokemon go. However, It is very difficult for me to find any. I can bike for 5 Kilometers and only find 2, maybe 3 on occasion. And the ones I am finding are low leveled ones. I do frequently have the White spinning pokeball loading on the side of my screen as well. My character is moving properly however on the map. Any help would be appreciated. I really want to enjoy this game.This is different from the other question because the other specific he lived in a low traffic area/rural. I live in a highly populated town. I also can specify that I dont see any when my friends find them right next to me.

Comment: As well, please don't label this a duplicate. The other question did not help me. From what I know people see the same Pokemon. When walking with friends I see absolutely none when they find them. I believe this is a bug, and not the games spawning habits.

Comment: If you believe this is a bug you should open a ticket with Niantic instead of posting here.

Comment: I have. I am trying all of my options to try and have a working game. Maybe someone else can help, as Niantic doesn't respond at all.

Comment: @Conner agreed. This person is in a public place. And accord the the link Frank put, it mentions you need to be in a public place, which means he's already in that step.

Comment: @Frank if this question has followed the requiredments of the linked one, why are you still duplicating this if this user has already met the requirements of the other question.

Comment: Not having Pokemon nearby due to where you live, and not having pokemon spawn at all are 2 different issues. Me and the other are in completely different situations entirely.

Comment: @JimJones Because it's asking the same thing.  Whether the answers help or not is irrelevant.  The question's been asked.